# Can't download Mavericks - I got a Mountain Lion CD, what to do?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, upgrade, install

This is the most silly question I'll ever ask, and I'm sorry for this.

But doing the following:

Step 1: https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/os-x-mavericks/id675248567
Step 2: http://www.apple.com/osx/how-to-upgrade/

I assumed there would be at least ONE way of downloading Mavericks, since.. It's free.. But aparently Apple assumes that 2014 was the year of removing download buttons?

I have a blank Mac Book Pro 2010.
This in turn has a OS X 10.8 DVD with it.

All I need, is to reinstall the machine!
I do not have a friend with a mac. I do not have a Apple store near by. I don't have Itunes (and can't install it either).
I do however have a DVD burner, a extremely fast internet and I don't mind fiddling in the command promt.

Any ideas what I could do? Again, sorry for this shitty question, been reinstalling Machines for over 15 years but never have a machine been this much of a headache.

Update:

This is what the site looks to like me...

[image]

For those who don't understand the dilemma of me having a 10.8 DVD.
According to their own forums, they've discontinued 10.8 as a installation option from the app store. They referr you to the Mavericks installation which should be a two press installation.. Assuming you have Another apple Product near by.

*"This item is temporarily unavailable. - Please try again later"*

[image http://www.technobuffalo.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/mountainlion-issue.jpeg](http://www.technobuffalo.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/mountainlion-issue.jpeg)

Comment: If I go to the Apple store the download is still there and active https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/os-x-mavericks/id675248567?mt=12

Comment: @Buscar웃 please feel free to screenshot that and post it here, cause either I'm blind, not as intutative as you or I just don't see it. Windows 7 with Internet Explorer here.

Comment: what happens when you click on the link I gave you

Comment: @Buscar웃 Updated the post with a screenshot of how the site looks if you're **not** on a Apple computer already.

Comment: Why can't you first install 10.8 from DVD and upgrade to Mavericks from there?

Comment: @patrix See the update. I just can't because after signing in with my apple ID to verify 1: My account, 2: My Mac Product it prompts me with this redicilous message.

Comment: Sorry I don't see the issue with 10.8 - Where does that message come from and why not use the 10.8 Safari rather than Windows - you are being confusing here - cut down the extraneous info and just what happens when you install 10.8 and then use app store to get Mavericks. i.e. it is unclear if you can install 10.8

Comment: No it's not unclear, i specificly written that i can not install 10.8 and i'm stuck with a blank computer and a DVD. I'll record a bloody video when i get home. this is such a PITA and even tho i'm greatful for all the help.. I'm about to just throw it in the bin :P

Comment: WHen do you get the error message, before or after installing 10.8? Is the 10.8 DVD the one delivered with your Mac or something you burnt on your own?

Comment: What prevents you from using [Internet Recovery?](http://osxdaily.com/2014/12/14/reinstall-os-x-mac-internet-recovery/)

Comment: @JMY1000 I'm fairly certain that this option uses the apple store to download the content, if so the issue might be the same. As of now this apple product is no longer alive and I can not verify this solution.

Comment: @Torxed Ah, okay. For future reference though, all you need is a working Mac that shipped with Lion or later/shipped with Snow Leopard and received the proper updates. OS X doesn't need to be currently installed on the machine (that would defeat the purpose).

Comment: When you say "blank computer" do you mean "new HDD installed thus NOTHING on it" or "No OS installed but original HDD"? If there's a Recovery Partition, boot to that (or try Internet Recovery). If not, are you inserting the disk or booting from it? If booting, are you using Disk Utility to wipe the HDD before attempting anything? The details help...

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with the screen shot of download button.

[image]

Comment: There you go, It's because you're ON a mac.. with Itunes/Apple Store built in.

Comment: Well, you can not get it another way.

Comment: If so, congratulations Apple, You've officially created a device you can lock yourself out of. **golfclap** -.- Even with 20 years or so of experience, you're in the gutter if someone comes in with a older, broken, OSX installation and their original DVD. fml..

Comment: I would gladly give you a copy of the installer (copy) I have but it is a 5.5 Gig file :( If you have a Google drive I could upload it there. It might take few hours :(

Comment: It's tempting, i do have a google drive. I'll get back to you on that one :) (Could Always create a bootable USB) :)

Answer (score -1):

1. Install OSX 10.8. Should be no problem on a 2010 MacBook Pro.
2. Boot the new system, launch AppStore and install 10.9.

Did you do this? Why do you involve a Windows 7 machine (which cannot help you here) ?

Comment: Except step one fails. If i could get to anything remotely Close to a working computer.. I would have upgraded via the integrated softwares boundled in the OS. But as i mentioned, i'm stuck with a Clean computer and a DVD that won't install.

Comment: @Torxed: Sorry, that was not clear. What is the message when the install fails? Is the DVD for a different type of Mac? This would be the case if it was bundled with an iMac, for example. Or is it the generic DVD which should work with all of them?

Comment: It's a downloaded (via app store) copy of OSX 10.8 Mountain Lion. I've used it like 20 times before without any problems. I've also used the same source for distributed inställs, but unfortunately I do not have access to these other apple Products as of now. But it is for this specific Product :)

Comment: Questions go into comments.

Comment: @Torxed: I still do not know the reason why the install of 10.8 with the DVD fails. Please try to give more details.